# How do I hyperlink an item returned from a queryset automatically

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a model

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(MyBankAccount, unique=False, related_name="transactions_sent") 
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(RecipientBankAccount, unique=False, related_name="transactions_received")
    created = models.DateField('transfer request date')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    createdby=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
```

which I display using

```
<li>{{ item.sender }} {{ item.receiver }} {{ item.amount }}</li>
```

I d like item.sender to be automatically hyperlinked to

http://example.com/johnsmith/trans/ where johnsmith is the name of the user that creates the transaction (aka createdby). I already implemented the view of this url. I just need to link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, presumably your url.py looks something like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # Patterns:

    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w-]+)/(?P<createdby>[\w-]+)/$', transaction, name="transaction"),
    ....
```

Your view is:

```
 def transaction(request, username, createdby):
     ...
```

Then your template fragment is:

```
 <a href="{% url transaction item.sender item.receiver %}">{{ item.sender }}</a>
```

Or you could define the following in your `Transaction` class (the urls.py file must remain):

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
     from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
     return reverse('transaction', kwargs={'username': self.sender, 'createdby': self.receiver})
```

And then your template would look like:

```
 <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.sender }}</a>
```

But geez, this is all [Django 101](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse).

Comment: You can put whatever you want into the textual component of a hyperlink.  As for the link generator itself, as long as the name is a unique identifier of the account, yes.  If it is not, you'll get a fairly standard error about "more than one row returned for get()."